# How do I get phantomJS to generate pdf that is just a single page that contains my page?

Tags: phantomjs

I am trying to create a pdf from a webpage using phantomJS. I want the pdf to just be a single page long that is the same height as my webpage. If I don't set paperSize or viewportSize at all then it creates a page that is almost the right height, it is just a little short by about 100px. If I detect page height and use that to set viewportSize I have the exact same problem, it's short by about 100px. Is there a way to get phantomJS to just create a pdf based on the webpage's size? I want it to be exact because the page is a dark colour and it looks really bad to have a big white block at the end of the page (which is what is there if I add a constant to viewport height to make it fit everything in one page).

My code to find height(Note: the height is the same whether I use body or the classname below to find it):

```
var size = page.evaluate(function() {
     var height = $('.export-athlete-detail-report').outerHeight(true);
     return {width: 700, height:height};
});

page.paperSize = size;
page.render(reportFile);
```

Comment: `page.viewportSize` isn't doing anything for rendering to PDF. You will need to use `page.paperSize`. Note that PhantomJS has different default DPI on different platforms (for when you're doing your pixel to cm calculation). I think on Windows it's 96 and on others 72 or something like that.

Comment: page.paperSize has the same effect for me. The page ends up slightly too long by variable amounts each time.

Comment: Also the phantomJS documentation says that if you don't set paperSize it will just use the size of the webpage, which is what I want.